# How is the extra first row with a dropdown created in the JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, tablecelleditor

Basically i am trying to understand the "multiple JTable cell editors per column" and come across the this article on the internet

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077465/learn-java/java-tip-102--add-multiple-jtable-cell-editors-per-column.html

Problem is in the output of the example code provided in the link, i don't understand how the first row with a dropdown created.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i don't understand how the first row with a dropdown created.

```
    add(b, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

A regular combo box is added to the panel. It is not part of the table.

The table is added as a separate component to the panel.